# How can I create a lock with Mutex?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have defined a Mutex in my class (global):

```
static Mutex fooMutex;
```

And I want to lock something so that the user is not allowed to see the effect of tapping the image more then once per 3 seconds:

```
private void Image_Tap_1(...)
{
            bool isRunnng = true;
            try
            {
                Mutex.OpenExisting("foo");
            }
            catch
            {
                isRunnng = false;
                fooMutex = new Mutex(true, "foo");
            }

            if (!isRunnng)
            {
                fooFadeIn.Begin();
                fooFadeIn.Completed += fooFadeIn_Completed;
            }
```

And dispose on Completed:

```
private void fooFadeIn_Completed(...)
{
   fooMutex.Dispose()
```

But this does not work, anyone got an idea?

Comment: I'm not convinced that a mutex is the best bet here since it may lock up the GUI thread. Maybe you should just disable the image and enable it again in 3 seconds using a timer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using a mutex or a timer, you can just store the time at which the image was last tapped:

```
private DateTime lastTap;

private void Image_Tap_1(...)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    if ((now - lastTap).TotalSeconds < 3)
    {
        return;
    }

    lastTap = now;

    // More than 3 seconds since last tap
    ...
}
```